# Como puedo cambiar el valor null de un string en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hola tengo un proyecto de windows form con C# que contiene un listbox en  el que con un boton add te permite añadir un maximo de 3 objetos y cuando seleccionas ese objeto te muestra las propiedades y te habilita el boton de remover cuando le da a remover causa un crasheo porque la variable string SLUI = listbox.items.selecteditem.tostring(); es null como convierto ese null a otro valor para que no crashee sin añadir un objeto al listbox

variable del selecteditem

```
public string SLUI;
```

Codigo del listbox

```
private void UI_Inspector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SLUI = UI_Inspector.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string T1C = "Text-1";
            string T2C = "Text-2";
            string T3C = "Text-3";
            RMVB.Visible = true;

            if (SLUI == null)
            {
                SLUI = "NONE";
            }

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T1C) == 0)
            {
                TX1P.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TX1P.Visible = false;
            }

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T2C) == 0)
            {
                TX2P.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TX2P.Visible = false;
            }

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T3C) == 0)
            {
                TX3P.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                TX3P.Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

RMVB es el nombre del boton
TX"numero"P es el panel de informacion del objeto
UI_inspector es el listbox
codigo del boton remover

```
        private void RMVB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SLUI = UI_Inspector.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string T1C = "Text-1";
            string T2C = "Text-2";
            string T3C = "Text-3";

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T1C) == 0)
            {
                Text1B.Visible = true;
                TX1P.Visible = false;
                UI_Inspector.Items.Remove(T1C);

            }

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T2C) == 0)
            {
                Text2B.Visible = true;
                TX2P.Visible = false;
                UI_Inspector.Items.Remove(T2C);
            }

            if (string.Compare(SLUI, T3C) == 0)
            {
                Text3B.Visible = true;
                TX3P.Visible = false;
                UI_Inspector.Items.Remove(T3C);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Y si verficas si hay un item seleccionado, y si no hay salis del metodo? porque querrias cambiar magicamente un null a otra cosa, cuando null es un valor perfectamente valido?

Comment: Usa operador `??`, quedando de esta manera `SLUI = UI_Inspector.SelectedItem.ToString()  ??  "otro valor"`

Comment: oye no me funciono en su lugar hice que el boton asigne un valor numerico a una variable y en el mismo codigo que detecta si el seleccionado y muestra sus propiedades hice que detecte si el valor es 1 despues borra el item seleccionado y si no checa que objeto esta en la lista para mostrar sus propiedades

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que no rompa la aplicacion debes validar que no sea `null` el `selectedItem` porque ahi estas queriendo ejecutar un método sobre un valor `null` y rompe. Para evitar que rompa podes hacer asi:

```
SLUI = UI_Inspector.SelectedItem?.ToString();`
```

agregas el `?` antes de ejecutar el metodo y con eso bastara para que no rompa ahí, pero despues tendras el problema que queres comparar un string con un valor `null`.
Otra forma es usar el operador `??` si algo es null setea con el valor que vos le pases.

```
SLUI = UI_Inspector.SelectedItem?.ToString()  ??  string.Empty;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.